# Does every call to write sends switches to kernel mode?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, glibc

I know that a call to the glibc "write" function calls in it's turn to the sys_call write function which is a kernel function.
 because sys_call is a kernel function the CPU has to change the ring to zero store the processes registers and so on.
But does it always switches to kernel mode? for example, if i do

```
write(-1,buffer,LENGTH)
```

does it still tries to find it in the file descriptors array?
I see in the glibc source code that it does check for fd>0 but i don't see any jump to the sys_call there (it seems like the baracks for main() ends before any call to the alias_write.

```
/* Write NBYTES of BUF to FD.  Return the number written, or -1.  */
ssize_t
__libc_write (int fd, const void *buf, size_t nbytes)
{
  if (nbytes == 0)
    return 0;
  if (fd < 0)
    {
      __set_errno (EBADF);
      return -1;
    }
  if (buf == NULL)
    {
      __set_errno (EINVAL);
      return -1;
    }

  __set_errno (ENOSYS);
  return -1;
}
libc_hidden_def (__libc_write)
stub_warning (write)

weak_alias (__libc_write, __write)
libc_hidden_weak (__write)
weak_alias (__libc_write, write)
#include <stub-tag.h>
```

So the question is both:

1. Where does the glibc actually calls the sys_write
2. Is it true that glibc doesn't call the sys_write if fd<0?

Answer (score 0):

> I see in the glibc source code that it does check for fd>0 but i don't see any jump to the sys_call there

You are looking at the wrong code.

There are multiple definitions of `__libc_write` used under different conditions. The one you looked at is in `io/write.c`.

The one that is *actually* used on Linux is generated from `sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S` and it *does* actually execute the switch to kernel mode (and back to user mode) even when `fd==-1`, etc.